# Batch Script - where is the error in below Batch file?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I am trying to do below thing in a batch file.

> 1. Check if a folder exists
> 2. If not, create the folder.
> 3. If the folder has created then provide Read permission to Everyone
> 4. Else show error that the folder has not created.

Below is the batch file (test.bat):

```
set FolderPath="%TEMP%\Data"
IF NOT EXIST %FolderPath% (MKDIR %FolderPath%)

IF EXIST %FolderPath% (icacls %FolderPath% /grant "Everyone":(OI)(CI)R)
ELSE (
ECHO ERROR: The folder %FolderPath% can not be found
GOTO Finish
)

:Finish
```

But while executing this test.bat file from cmd, I am getting below error:

```
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Data" (MKDIR "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Data" )
(CI)R) was unexpected at this time.
IF EXIST "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Data" (
icacls "C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Data" /grant "Everyone":(OI)(CI)R)
```

I can see that the folder has been created, but no permission set. Can you please tell me why this error has shown ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **WHY** is that batch has ambiguous syntax and can't tell the difference between a `)` to close a block and a `)` appearing as an ordinary character in a filename or whatever.

The **HOW** is to escape the "ordinary" characters with a preceding caret `^)` so `"Everyone":(OI)(CI)R)` becomes `"Everyone":(OI^)(CI^)R)`

Note however that the `)` following the `R` is **closing the block** and thus should **NOT** have a caret **BUT** this would introduce a further syntax error - the **ELSE** must be on the same physical line as the preceding `)` hence you would need

```
IF EXIST %FolderPath% (icacls %FolderPath% /grant "Everyone":(OI^)(CI^)R
) ELSE (
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "folderpath=test"
IF EXIST "%FolderPath%" icacls %FolderPath% /grant "Everyone":(OI)(CI)R
IF NOT EXIST "%FolderPath%" (
    ECHO ERROR: The folder %FolderPath% can not be found
    GOTO Finish
)
```